# How to show a TIF image full screen on secondary monitor in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a series of images stored in a directory and want to show them successively on the secondary monitor in full screen mode.

I have no clues whatsoever of displaying image full screen mode..
Any idea how to do this in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a borderless form, using its BackgroundImage to show the image.  Make it as large as the secondary screen.  Like this:

```
    public static Form ShowImage(Image image) {
        Form frm = new Form();
        frm.ControlBox = false;
        frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        frm.BackgroundImage = image;
        frm.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
        Screen scr = Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1 ? Screen.AllScreens[1] : Screen.PrimaryScreen;
        frm.Location = new Point(scr.Bounds.Left, scr.Bounds.Top);
        frm.Size = scr.Bounds.Size;
        frm.BackColor = Color.Black;
        frm.Show();
        return frm;
    }
```

Note that it returns a Form object, call its Close() method to get rid of the image again.

Comment: Actually I want the actual res of the image to be show so if its a 800 x 600 image it should show as the same without scaling and zooming.

Comment: Change BackkgroundImageLayout.  If you have additional requirements then use the form's Paint event.

Answer (score 2):

Use SetWindowPos from the WinAPI.

Example:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hwndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int width, int height, uint flags);   
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    SetWindowPos(this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, 64);
}
```

replace `PrimaryScreen` with the choosen screen.

I don't know what all can be done with the image. you can just use a Picturebox or create your on control and display it with GDI.

Comment: You mean, I should add a picture box into the form and then set the picture box size the same as the form, right?